# How to disable assistance/hyperlink to Billing address field on Account Object, in lightning in salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Billing Address value is shown as hyperlink, in Lightning in Salesforce1. 
When clicked then nothing happens. But if a user refreshes that page, or use that value to new page, then the value start appearing twice.

The screen shots will help you understand better. I think its happening after Summer16. Also this feature is seen in Ipad/Iphone, where it tries to detect the phone and address value and tries to provide assistance on it.[image]

[image: Snippet with double values]

Comment: Have you logged a case with support? That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable and this seems a salesforce standard functionality, but can you try with formula field to populate the billing address information and display it in your mobile view and remove with the Billing Address field.